# Keyvault MSI with Spring boot : How to config keyvault to use Azure cli credentials instead of managed identity while running on local?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I created a simple spring boot app to retrieve secrets from keyvault.
I added the following dependency to work around with,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and added the following in application.properties

```
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.uri=<URL>

#keys
mySecretProperty=secret
```

and my main application,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KeyVaultSample implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${mySecretProperty}")
    private String mySecretProperty;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KeyVaultSample.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("property your-property-name value is: " + mySecretProperty);
    }
}
```

But every time I tried to run the above app on local, it tries to use ManagedIdentityCredential to connect. So I added a configuration class for creating a bean for SecretClient with AzureCliCredential, but then too, the results are the same.

My Configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

@Bean
public SecretClient secretClient() {
  AzureCliCredential az = new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
  SecretClient sec = new SecretClientBuilder().vaultUrl("<url>")
  .credential(az).buildClient();
  return sec;
 }
}​
```

I'm looking for ways I could use/test this keyvault on my local.
Is there any configuration I could put in the properties file which would make it use AzureCliCredential instead of ManagedIdentityCredential?

Answer (score 0):

[`azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable) uses MSI / Managed identities.

If you would like to authenticate with Azure CLI, just use [`azure-identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable) and [`azure-security-keyvault-secrets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable).

```
public void getSecretWithAzureCliCredential() {
    AzureCliCredential cliCredential = new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();

    // Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter
    SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl("https://{YOUR_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net")
        .credential(cliCredential)
        .buildClient();

    KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret("<secret-name>");
    System.out.printf("Retrieved secret with name \"%s\" and value \"%s\"%n", secret.getName(), secret.getValue());

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pamela, I have one doubt, does the **azure-security-keyvault-secrets** also supports spring property source, i.e making use of placeholder for the secrets.

Comment: No, it doesn't provide a Spring `PropertySource`.

Comment: Hi @Pamela, I just found out that **azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter** along with **azure-client-authentication** does supports MSI. I tried by not setting any client-id and client-key in my properties file and it threw an error for not able to connect to the IMDSEndpoint with MSICredentials on local machine, which is fair. 
The question again arises, can I make any config or set any property telling it to take AzureCliCredentials?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need the real thing in local (a test double can be fine instead of Azure Key Vault) you could try Lowkey Vault too! It supports keys and secrets using a local container and you can fake the authentication using a simple basic auth.

Project home: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault

Java POC (although not using the Spring Boot starter): https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault-example